# Edit(Mutate) object property inside a reducer in NgRx

Tags: angular, functional-programming, ngrx

I'm having troubles when trying to edit a property inside an object. I'm using PokeApi to fetch Pokémon and then, with a button, add them into a cart.

**Interface**

```
export interface PokemonModel {
  name: string;
  url: string;
  quantity: number;
  isAdded: boolean;
}
```

**Action**

```
export const addToCart = createAction(
  '[Cart List] Add To cart',
  props<{ pokemon: PokemonModel }>()
);
```

**Reducer**

```
on(addToCart, (state, { pokemon }) => {
  pokemon.isAdded = true; // <-- Cannot add property isAdded, object is not extensible

  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    error: false,
    pokemons: [
      ...state.pokemons.filter((pk) => pk.name !== pokemon.name),
      ...[pokemon],
    ],
  };
}),
```

**Function**

```
addPokemon(pokemon: any) {
  this.store.dispatch(addToCart({ pokemon }));
}
```

The thing is, I need to edit the value for `isAdded` property.

I have tried with `Object.preventExtensions(pokemon)` no matter if I add above or below the property, the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small reminder: Because reducers are `pure functions` you can't `mutate` the `state`  manually, you need to create a copy and edit the copy (this is all `functional programming princicples`.

Create a copy of Pokémon:

```js
let pokemonCopy = {...pokemon, isAdded: true}
```

And for the spread operator, you're combining both `computed property` in objects and `spread operator` at the same time, which I don't think it's gonna work for you.

You need to simply append it to the new state

```js
 return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    error: false,
    pokemons: [
      ...state.pokemons.filter((pk) => pk.name !== pokemon.name),
      pokemonCopy,
    ],
  };
```

and if the order matter to you, I'd recommend

```js
return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    error: false,
    pokemons: [
      ...state.pokemons.map((pk) => pk.name == pokemon.name ? pokemonCopy : pk),
    ],
  };
```

Comment: It seemed to me that I had been doing something wrong. Thanks for the approach but the same error occurs. I think I need to redefine the whole ngrx state.

Comment: Can you share any errors in console/browser so we can help? or is the error muted somehow? Try using Redux-devtool to observe your state changes too (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en)

Comment: Yes! I'm using that extension but it said nothing. The error in console is 'Cannot add property isAdded, object is not extensible' but I was able to resolve it with the comment below.

Comment: Okay, on which line the error is occurring? is it on: ```let pokemonCopy = {...pokemon, isAdded: true}
```

Comment: Yes, that line. I have tried again and guess what, now works! maybe because I have combined your solution with the `pokemon.isAdded = true;` of the first comment, so, thanks again! I think your solution it's more 'clean', don't you?

Comment: To be honest, I think that the action object is not a normal JS object that's why it's preventing you from manually mutating it (where in principle action can be mutable I think, while state are definitely not), so don't mix the manual mutation with the copy and create style in your code, glad you have it fixed

Comment: Very clear now, I'm starting with NgRx so really appreciate your comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to change the payload inside reducers as they are intended to be pure functions. I would recommend you to update the payload before dispatching as shown below. Once dispatched, you should not be worrying about editing payload

```
addPokemon(pokemon: any) {
  pokemon.isAdded = true;
  this.store.dispatch(addToCart({ pokemon }));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but the same error appears, thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is a much better  approach if you better your reducer's as clean as possible like this for example

```
on(storeActions.updateCurrentChat, (state, { currentChat }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      currentChat: { ...currentChat },
    };
  })
```

where you could actually mutate the data and pass them

```
public stopPriting(id: string) {
    const updatedCurrenctChat = structuredClone(this.currentChat$);
    const message = updatedCurrenctChat.messages.find(
      (chat) => chat.id === id
    ) as ConvI;
    // WhichType<typeof this.currentChat$,'isPrinted'>

    (message as MeowGPTI).isPrinted = true;
    // (<MeowGPTI>message).isPrinted = true;

    this.store.dispatch(
      storeActions.updateCurrentChat({ currentChat: updatedCurrenctChat })
    );
  }
```

I believe there's different ways of cloning objects like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)` or with `loadash` but it all depends on your case